# Improve search functionality delay while using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search, entity-framework-6, asqueryable

If I prepare a query using AsQueryable and append the search criteria dynamically in entity framework, it takes so long compare to SQL query. Is there any alternate approach to create dynamic queries in entity framework?

Thank you
Jeremy

Comment: put the SQL into a stored procedure and call it by using EF?

Comment: `AsQueryable()` also just generates SQL. Read [ask], show a [mcve] including the generated SQL and compare the execution plan with your hand-crafted SQL.

Answer (score -1):

How about write raw sql? this may not be the best option, but is an alternative.. must compare times

You can use someting like this to do the job.

```
        //an entity to return
        AltPedVendaModel ret = new AltPedVendaModel();

        var conn = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                string query = $"select * from .......";
                command.CommandText = query;
                DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //read line to line 
                        ret = new AltPedVendaModel
                        {
                            IsOk = reader.GetBoolean(0),
                            Awb = reader.GetString(1),
                            Invoice = reader.GetString(2),
                            Po = reader.GetString(3),
                            Obs = reader.GetString(4),
                            Frete = reader.GetDecimal(5),
                        };

                    }
                }
                reader.Dispose();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return ret;
```

Comment: u can use this cote to run an Stored procedure too.. use command.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of command.ExecuteReader() if your SP dont return rows..